# Stop android activity from being destroyed on locale change

Tags: java, android, android-activity, locale

I have an android app that handles locale changes on its own.
When I leave the app and change the locale "Application->onConfigurationChanged" is called (NOT Activity->onConfigurationChanged) and when I resume the app the activity is destroyed and restarted.

I have already placed `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|locale"` in the activity section in the manifest.

How can I stop my activity from being recreated on resume after a locale change?

Comment: are you creating it on onResume ? as when you go to change the locale your onResume will be called so if you are doing that then removed the code from onresume and place it to onCreate !!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default reaction to configuration changes in Android
is to destroy the activity. To avoid this happening for
locale changes, we had the "locale" configuration change
registered in the default AndroidManifest.xml, however,
you also need to register that you are handling the
layoutDirection change, otherwise Android will not
call onConfigurationChange() for language changes, but
tear down the activity instead.

Adding `android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"` prevents the activity from being destroyed on resume.

[Source](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/113488)

Comment: That is the answer! Thanks so much, was wondering the same thing.

Comment: Thx, I was probably going to lost few hours without you !

Comment: omg thank for this answer. I'm stuck with this too. Adding "layoutDirection|locale' did the trick

Comment: You are right; adding layoutDirection helped; locale itself was not enough. IMHO, it's a defect in Android API...

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your activity inside the mainfest file, 
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"