# How to prevent screen "flash" on locale change in Jetpack Compose with AppCompatDelegate?

Tags: android, localization, android-jetpack-compose, locale, android-appcompat

I added an In-app language picker for my Compose App following [this article.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages)
but everytime I change the language the screen flashes. I guess it is due to configuration changes

I downloaded the [sample app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages) out of curiosity and it has the same issue.

Is there a way to prevent these "flashes" or add a nice transition animation? Ideally I would like to just reload the string resources

[Here is a gif about the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDMGt.gif)

I tried overwriting the recreate() method in the MainActivity and editing the androidmanifest file based on these couldn't prevent the "flash" :
[How do I keep my android activity keep on going even if somebody switches from dark mode to day mode or vice versa (using Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71614707/how-do-i-keep-my-android-activity-keep-on-going-even-if-somebody-switches-from-d)
[How to trigger recomposition after updateConfiguration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70991087/how-to-trigger-recomposition-after-updateconfiguration)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you found a solition for this?

Comment: Yes I did, please check the accepted answer @musclebananas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution for this:

**Short answer:** Add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml `activity` tag

```
android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection"
```

**Long answer:** Read these:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config
- [Stop android activity from being destroyed on locale change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900633/stop-android-activity-from-being-destroyed-on-locale-change)